# concatenate sql rows into a python dict

Tags: python

I have a sql table like :

| tableName | tableCol |
| --- | --- |
| customer | firstname |
| customer | surname |
| address | address1 |
| address | address2 |

how can I combine the rows together in python dict and have:

data =

```
   {customer, [firstname,surname],

    address, [address1,address2]}
```

thank you!

I've tried:
data = [dict(zip(row.tablename, row.tableCol))
for row in sql_query]

but doesn't get the expected results.
looks like it selects every letter into its own key:value.

Comment: your example desired output is not a valid dictionary (has repeated key names)

Comment: do you want a list of individual dictionaries (one for each table name)?  or a single dictionary with all tables?

Comment: I've edited the output .  a single dictionary contained the table. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data = [dict(zip(row.tablename, row.tableCol)) for row in sql_query]`
is a sort of wishful-thinking attempt

If we think through how it works we can see why the result is wrong:

- we create a new dict for each row
- the dict is made by zipping the values of `tableName` and `tableCol` for that row, which are both strings, so the zip produces pairs of individual letters from each column which then become the key: value pairs of the resulting dictionary

If we actually want a single dict keyed by `tableName` with a list of `tableCol` values for each then the simplest way to output this is:

```py
data = {}
for row in rows:
    data.setdefault(row.tableName, []).append(row.tableCol)
```

```
In [6]: data
Out[6]:
{'customer': ['firstname', 'surname'],
 'address': ['address1', 'address2']}
```

If the rows are already sorted by `tableName` when retrieved from the db we could also make a version that uses [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
import itertools

data = {
    key: [row.tableCol for row in group]
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted_rows, lambda r: r.tableName)
}
```

```
In [13]: data
Out[13]:
{'address': ['address1', 'address2'],
 'customer': ['firstname', 'surname']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
outputDict = {}
for row in table_data:
    if row[0] not in sampleDict.keys():
        outputDict[row[0]] = []
    outputDict[row[0]].append(row[1])
```

here, table_data is a list of rows from the table in following format -

```
[["customer","firstname"],
["customer","surname"],
["address","address1"],
["address","address2"]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data = {}
for row in rows:
    data.setdefault(row.tableName, []).append(row.tableCol)
In [6]: data
Out[6]: {'customer': ['firstname', 'surname'],
 'address': ['address1', 'address2']}
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.